# Is there a way to block on a socket and a blockingqueue in java?

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, blockingqueue

Ideally I'd like to add my blocking queue to a selector so I can block reading from a socket or until an item appears on the blocking queue.

Is there some higher level selector-like function that operates on disparate types like these?

I could go the cheesy way out and fire off 2 threads and have each one block individually, but it would be cleaner to have one function that could block on both types of object.

Is there a way to grab the monitor for each object that is being blocked on and use a selector-like object to block on both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can have one thread block on both.  If the issue is that you have a worker thread that can either accept a task from the queue or directly from a socket, it would probably be cleaner to have a separate thread that reads tasks from the socket and puts them on the queue.

Comment: It would be cleaner if all things that could block derive from something called BlockingThing. :-)